# ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'value'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript

I know this question is asked a lot of times but I can't figure out what is the problem. I am trying to add string to an array of strings in mongoDB. When user submit form I get this error because for loop only see that string but when I reload page it correctly show array.

**Component Template**

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="skill" *ngFor="let skill of profile.skills">{{skill}}</div>
</div>
```

**Component Class**

Profile is a model and it has propery like skills?: Array

```
profile: Profile = {};

onSubmit() {
  this.profile.skills = this.form.value.skill;
  this.userService.addSkills(this.profile, this.id)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
}
```

**Service**

```
addSkills(profile: Profile, id: string) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(profile);
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/profile/skills/' + id, body, { headers: headers })
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
}
```

When I put console.log(this.profile.skills) in ngOnInit
 it logs an array but when I log right before redirect on submit It only log that single string that is added. I have to mention that skills are properly displayed on reload. Only getting this error when submitting form. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You need to add the new `skill` to the array, instead of overwriting the array with the `skill` itself. e.g. `this.profile.skills.push(this.form.value.skill);`.

Comment: @serpent5 Tnx, It fixed the problem